# The data area passed to a system call is too small when saving with C# EF6

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a C#, Winforms EF6 application. Database is SQL Server Compact 4.
In some computers (most work fine) I get the Exception "The data area passed to a system call is too small" when saving a simple object like in the code below

```
        public void Add(SimpleObject simpleObject)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new MyDbContext())
                {
                    db.SimpleObjects.AddOrUpdate(e => e.Description, simpleObject);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.ErrorException("Add", ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

SimpleObject is extremely simple with 2 columns ([ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1), [DESCRIPTION] NVARCHAR(4000)). The instances that throw exceptions have in the Description field common text (bellow 150 characters) that are in most computers normally saved. Command AddOrUpdate throws the exception.

Full Exception details logged with NLog:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The data area passed to a system call is too small.
>      at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
>      at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
>      at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeMultiCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](DbSet`1 set, IEnumerable`1 identifyingProperties, InternalSet`1 internalSet, TEntity[] entities)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](IDbSet`1 set, Expression`1 identifierExpression, TEntity[] entities)>

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using AddOrUpdate?

Comment: Some AddOrUpdate malfunction is causing the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to SQL CE 4.0 SP1, as it contains a fix for that issue - see http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/03/sql-server-compact-40-sp1-ctp1.html

Comment: I will try it and mark it as answer if it works. Thanks!